# jquery ajax links work / not work It works through time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

pls help, i understand why ajax link work or nor work when click ?
It works through time

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    function getXmlHttp(){
        ...... // simply ajax
    }
    var cont = document.getElementById('wrapper1');
    var As = document.getElementsByTagName("A"); // get links
    for(var i = 0, l = As.length; i < l; i ++){
        As[i].onclick = function(href){ // code
            As[i].addEventListener('click', false); // code
            return function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp()
                xmlhttp.open('GET', href, false);
                xmlhttp.send(null);
                if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {cont.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;}
            }
        }(As[i].href);

        As[i].href = "javascript: void 0"; // right code ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your existing code, you are trying to bind a click handler to *all* anchor elements, which will make an Ajax request to the URL in the `href` attribute, and display the results in the `id="wrapper1"` element.

Your code is a bit confusing without any indenting, but it looks mostly OK except that you are trying to make use of the Ajax response *without* waiting for the [`onreadystatechange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) - you need to wrap that `if(xmlhttp.status)...` line in a handler as follows:

```
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp()
xmlhttp.open('GET', href, false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {   // <---- add this
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {cont.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;}
};
```

Also, this line:

```
As[i].addEventListener('click', false);
```

...is incorrect because `addEventListener()` expects a function reference as its second argument, and also it just doesn't make sense to call it at all when you are already setting a click handler on the element via `.onclick = ...`.

Given you have tagged your question with jQuery, here is an alternative implementation that is quite a bit shorter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {           // when DOM is ready
  var $cont = $("#wrapper1");            // save reference to output element

  $("a").click(function(e) {             // bind click to all anchors
    e.preventDefault();                  // prevent default click behavior
    $.get(this.href, function(result) {  // Ajax get request to href URL
      $cont.html(result);                // put result in output element
    });
  });
});
```